# Searching for this particular font, It's seen on John Dahlback's older set covers

Tags: font-identification

[image: Here's the image]

The font here is the one I'm looking for, it looks similar to Chilopod, but not as round.

Comment: When you see something like this then you should think " How long would it take to draw" and see its a single stroke, it would take 10 minutes. On the otherhand if it was a font and youd like to edit it slightly 10 mintes. That means it may not be a font at all. Considering the kerning and line to line alignment, its probably drawn or atleast editted so much it might aswell be.

Comment: ahhh i gotcha, thanks fam :)